# Webscraping with varying page numbers

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm trying to webscrape a bunch of profiles. Each profile has a collection of videos. I'm trying to webscrape information about each video. The problem I'm running into is that each profile uploads a different number of videos, so the number of pages containing videos per profile varies. For instance, one profile has 45 pages of videos, as you can see by the html below:

```
<div class="pagination "><ul><li><a class="active" href="">1</a></li><li><a href="#1">2</a></li><li><a href="#2">3</a></li><li><a href="#3">4</a></li><li><a href="#4">5</a></li><li><a href="#5">6</a></li><li><a href="#6">7</a></li><li><a href="#7">8</a></li><li><a href="#8">9</a></li><li><a href="#9">10</a></li><li><a href="#10">11</a></li><li class="no-page"><a href="#" class="ellipsis last-ellipsis">...</a><li><a href="#44" class="last-page">45</a></li><li><a href="#1" class="no-page next-page"><span class="mobile-hide">Next</span>
```

While another profile has 2 pages

```
<div class="pagination "><ul><li><a class="active" href="">1</a></li><li><a href="#1">2</a></li><li><a href="#1" class="no-page next-page"><span class="mobile-hide">Next</span>
```

My question is, how do I account for the varying changes in page? I was thinking of making a for loop and just adding a random number at the end, like

```
for i in range(0,1000): 
  new_url = 'url' + str(i)
```

where i accounts for the page, but I want to know if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: Website URL pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to thank everyone who did answer for taking the time to answer my question. I figured out the answer - or at least what worked for me- and decided to share in case it would be helpful for anyone else.

```
url = 'insert url'
re = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content,'html.parser')

#look for pagination class
page = soup.find(class_='pagination')

#create list to include all page numbers
href=[]

#look for all 'li' tags as the users above suggested
links = page.findAll('li')
for link in links:
   href += [link.find('a',href=True).text]  

'''
href will now include all pages and the word Next. 
So for instance it will look something like this:[1,2,3...,44,Next]. 
I want to get 44, which will be href[-2] and then convert that to an int for 
a for loop. In the for loop add + 1 because it will iterate to i-1, instead of 
i. For instance, if you're iterating (0,44), the last output of i will be 43, 
which is why we +1
'''

for i in range(0, int(href[-2])+1):
   new_url = url + str(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the `<li>...</li>` elements of the `<div class="pagination "><ul>`
2. Exclude the **last one** by its class `<li class="no-page">`
3. Parse the **"href"** and build your next url destinations.
4. Scrape every new url destination.

Answer (score 0):

The *"skeleton"* of the loop can look like this:

```
url = 'http://url/?page={page}'

page = 1
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, 'html.parser')

    # ...

    # do we have next page?
    next_page = soup.select_one('.next-page')
    
    # no, so break from the loop
    if not next_page:
        break

    page += 1
```

You can have infinite loop `while True:` and you will break the loop only if there's no next page (if there isn't any `class="next-page"` tag on the last page).